# how to do yocto testing like weekly test full pass test and release test?

Tags: yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I am trying to do **`yocto testing`**:

1. how to do yocto daily test report?
2. how to do weekly test?
3. yocto full pass test?
4. sanity test for yocto?
   please guide me to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to expand on what you want to actually do.

If you want to run the QA then you want to look at `oe-selftest` and `bitbake core-image-sato -c testimage`.